# imtcp imtcp framing error in received tcp message from peer

Tags: rsyslog

I am trying to set datetime format for the remote server but I keep getting error whenever I set the following template:

```
$template temp1,"%timegenerated:::date-rfc3339% %HOSTNAME% %msg%\n"
```

and I set the template for remote machine like this:

```
@@xxx.xx.xx.xxx:514;temp1
```

I get the following error on remote machine:

> imtcp imtcp framing error in received tcp message from peer

Note that everything works fine for this template:

```
$template temp1,"%timegenerated% %HOSTNAME% %msg%\n"
```

What am I doing wrong? How do I change the time format for remote machine according to RFC3339 successfully.